# jQuery.clone() & keep Prototype.js event observer applied via Event.observe()

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am integrating an external library into a project of mine. Unfortunately this external library uses Prototype, while my project depends on jQuery. I have this working except for the following problem:

1. On page load, Prototype applies an event observer via `Event.observe()` to a DOM element on the page
2. Upon some user interaction, this DOM element is then cloned using `jQuery.clone()` so that it can be used on another part of the page

Unfortunately the cloned copy isn't bound to Prototype's `Event.observe()` listener anymore.

I have already noticed that jQuery.clone() accepts two parameters to also copy the event handlers, but I suppose this only works for jQuery's own event handlers, not the ones applied via another library.

Does anybody know how I could create a copy of the element without it loosing its Prototype event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">with content</div>
```

This will clone the element

```
var newdiv = $('mydiv').clone();
```

If you want to have the clone do a deep clone and clone all the child elements as well pass `true`

```
var newdiv = $('mydiv').clone(true);
```

**However** the `clone()` method does not copy the observers - so I suggest putting a observer higher in the DOM to watch for the events that bubble up to it.

Given this HTML

```
<div id="mydiv" class="cloneclick">with content</div>
```

and attaching to `<body>` for example, the cloned div will still have the `cloneclick` class and will still trigger the event handler

```
$$('body').first().on('click','.cloneclick',function(){
    alert('click happened');
});
```

Comment: Yes, I also though about moving the observer to a higher level. I was trying to avoid this as I don't know the first bit about Prototypejs.